# How to stop Wildfly11 loading jar dependency webservices

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-11

I need some help preventing Wildfly11 from automatically loading classes annotated with `@WebServiceProvider` in jar dependencies.

The dependency is 3rd party so it's not possible for me to change the contents of the jar or to make source code changes to it.

I have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This completely disabled webservices support, which is fine for now (although I do get other errors that doesn't seem to break anything)...but ideally I just wanted to exclude the jar, or certain classes/class paths from being automatically loaded.

What I have discovered thus far is, the `@WebServiceProvider` annotation is not part of the beans scanning. So adding `bean-discovery-mode="none"` to `beans.xml` has no affect. Adding a `jboss-scanning.xml` had no luck excluding the jar or classes..

**Application details:**

- **Type:** SpringBoot 2 war file
- **Container:** War deployed to Wildfly 11 in standalone mode
- **Why Wildfly?!** Client dictated.
- **Exclude the jar?** I don't want to exclude the entire jar from the classpath, there are classes I need. I just don't want the automagic to load stuff I didn't ask for.

**Update 1**
Here is the log entry
Yes it complains about a WSDL... but I don't even want this class to load at all in the first place.

```
11:56:50,990 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."studyquotation.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."studyquotation.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "studyquotation.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.wsf.spi.WSFException: JBWS024109: Could not get WSDL contract for endpoint com.ca.gen80.wsrt.router.GenServiceRouter at WEB-INF/wsdl/router.wsdl
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder.getWsdlLocationURL(MetadataBuilder.java:283)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder.build(MetadataBuilder.java:90)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.DescriptorDeploymentAspect.start(DescriptorDeploymentAspect.java:42)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
```

The class is annotated with

```
@WebServiceProvider(
    serviceName = "router",
    portName = "routerSoapPort",
    targetNamespace = "http://GenStudio/router/",
    wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/router.wsdl"
)
@BindingType("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http")
@ServiceMode(Mode.MESSAGE)
public class GenServiceRouter implements Provider<SOAPMessage> {
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to exclude auto loading some dependency, i have not tried but may be it will help ful to you

Content of my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <!-- Add picketlink module dependency -->
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.picketlink" annotations="true">
        <imports>
           <exclude path="org/picketlink/identity/federation/core/pdp/**"/>
        </imports>
      </module>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Hi, how should I adapt this for my use case? It seems like you are excluding picketlink libraries, not custom classes?
The maven dependency I have is on `allfusion:genrt:80` and the class causing trouble is `com.ca.gen80.wsrt.router.GenServiceRouter`. I tried just changing the exclude path from your example to `com/ca/gen80/wsrt/**`. No luck...not really sure what this is configuring...

Comment: @trojanc, Hope you resolved the issue. I am facing this issue right now. can you please share your knowledge on fixing this issue